# Dry Hopping Cider

Tags: fermentation, hops, cider, dry-hop, process

I’ve taken to making Cider and quite enjoy it. I now finalize my fermentation (temp controlled) at 1.015Gs before bottling or kegging. In the case of bottling I still prime with sugar and then test after two weeks - once I’m back at 1.015Gs I pasteurize the sealed bottles to halt fermentation. I am interested in hopping my cider now but I’m unsure of the process to follow.

I imagine it’s all dry hopping, but what hops, for how long and at what stage?

Additionally will the final pasteurizing process change the flavor because of the hopping?

What do you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What hops is totally up to you, but I prefer to choose falvoring hops over bittering hops since cider has more than enough bitterness in general.

You can use about 5g of hops per liter of cider and let it sit for 3 to 7 days.  Ideally you will dry hop when primary fermentation is finished and after racking at least once.

Some people have suggested making a hop tea, but I never tried that.

There is a lot of trial and error to achieve your ideal result, so if you can split your batch in two (or more), you can try different hops and techniques and then compare the results.  Use those results to refine your process for next time.